# Drop chance on the Badaboom?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am trying to get [Badaboom](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Badaboom) and I already know that you have to kill King Mong over and over. But I was wondering, what is the drop chance and also do you have to be in true vault hunter mode to get it? I am just in normal mode and I can not seem to get it. I have killed King Mong probably over 50 times by now.

I have already tried playing with my friend because I know the drop chance is a lot higher with other people but I still couldn't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, you do realize that each legendary has it's own boss that has a significantly higher chance to drop a certain legendary weapon, right? That graph is just for world drops, the 1 out of 10000 thing - as in, a Marauder dropping the Nukem. The Bunker's assigned Legends are the Sham and the Bitch, and it seems to have about a 5% chance to drop the Sham or the Bitch in my experience. (UVHM) Plus, don't farm in Normal mode, once you get it, (Level 30 Max) by TVHM level 35 white rocket launchers will be significantly better. Farm one at level 50, if you don't have any DLC's.

Comment: But if you really wanted to, you COULD get the Badaboom in Normal mode.

Answer (score 7):

I found this table from the [Gearbox website](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/2013/09/inside-the-box-the-borderlands-2-loot-system/) about drops rates.  The Badaboom is a legendary item, making its odds of dropping a 1 and 10000 chance.

[image: drop rate image]

But that is just for a **legendary item**.  From what I can gather, there are pools of weapons (SMG pool, pistol pool, etc.), manufacturer pools, and more.  It also considers what kind of bandit you killed, (regular bandit, badass, super badass, etc.). All of these pools have to be taken into consideration when calculating the odds.

There is also a separate pool that determines what kind of item will drop (such as a shield, grenade mod, weapon, etc.).  Here is an image of how that pool looks:

[image: items pool image]

The website describes this pool as:

> ...a graph showing the relative chances of each item pool being chosen from our raffle. The entire bar represents all of the tickets in our jar. Each colored segment is equal to the number of tickets each pool has and therefore their relative chances of being chosen.

It gets more complicated with things like relics, specifically the Vault Hunter relic, which makes rarer items drops more common.

To sum it up, here's how the game goes through determining what to drop (with a pistol example included):

[image: determine drop image]

Without knowing the odds for things like the manufacturer pool and specific weapon pools, it makes calculating the actual odds impossible. I couldn't find these odds on that website.  Hopefully I at least gave you an idea of what to expect.